# Automata view in ispin

Tags: promela, spin

I'm new to ispin and promela coding. I managed to get the automata to view working in ispin but the problem I am having at the moment is that when the automata are bit complex the labels texts(transition label, state name) get really small that I can't read. Even if I click the zoom in button, it only enlarges the state diagram but the texts remain the same. Is there any way to increase the font size of the automata view texts?